# Swagger UI path not using path in flask restplus

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

In our code:

```
app = Flask(name)
blueprint = Blueprint('api',name,url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(blueprint, doc='/doc/')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

From the log..it's not using the prefix...swaggerui is off root.

```
 "GET /swaggerui/bower/swagger-ui/dist/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 0 
    "http://10.99.72.221:5002/api/doc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
     10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 
     Safari/603.3.8"
```

It's causing issues for AWS Application Load Balancer, as the only route I can define is /api, since it's running inside a Docker container.

Is there a way to insert a path in front of /swaggerui?